# How to convert char type to timestamp?

Tags: postgresql

I am dealing with the table which has date information in CHar(20) type. This date is in dd.mm.yyyy HH.MM.SS format but my pgadmin has Month first format. I tried editing posgres config file to change the date format. I tried to use SET timezone and then tried to convert type to timestamp but nothing is working. How can I convert following column into timestamp format? I followed miost of the answers here on stackoverflow but getting out of range error  even after using set function or editing config file.

[image]

Comment: Use the to_timestamp function and specify the format of your data as the second parameter: Thus *to_timestamp(data_value, 'data_format')* See [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-formatting.html).

Comment: @Belayer COuld you write a sample answer?

Answer (score 2):

Use `to_timestamp`:

```
to_timestamp(stringcol, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI')
```

To change the data type of the column, which is highly commendable:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER date1 TYPE timestamp
   USING CAST (to_timestamp(date1, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') AS timestamp);
```

Comment: This does work, but could you tell me how can I use it to change the column in table to have this structure embedded.

Comment: I have added the statement. That is the right thing to do!